# How to use JSON web service(Jquery)

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using MusicBrainz' [JSON web service](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/JSON_Web_Service) and I'm having a problem.

First of all, I'm trying to get info from this(only part of it):

```
"recordings":[
                {
                    "id":"0ef614a0-9fee-42d5-b1c8-385d3d889a6c",
                    "score":"100",
                    "title":"Come as You Are (Dirty dub)",
                    "length":505000,
                    "video":null,
                    "artist-credit":[
                                      {
                                         "artist":{
                                                    "id":"5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da",
                                                    "name":"Nirvana",
                                                    "sort-name":"Nirvana",
                                                    "disambiguation":"90s US grunge band",
```

And I was able to reach "artist" part by doing this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#bt1").on('click', searchArtist);
});
function searchArtist(){
    var keyword = $("#keyword").val();
    $.get("http://www.musicbrainz.org/ws/2/recording/?query=artist:"+keyword+"&fmt=json", function(data){
        $.each(data["recordings"], function(){
            $.each(this["artist-credit"],function(){
                $.each(this["artist"],function(){
                        $("#result").append(this.toString()+"<br>");
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

By this I'm getting everything inside "artist". But what I want to do is to get only "id". I've tried if statement but I got undefined. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. That "artist" didn't have [], which means it's not an array. I only needed 2 each statements for the two arrays and for "artist", all I need to do was this.artist.id to get what I wanted.